# MySQL Replication: Slave cannot communicate with master (Got an error reading communication packets)

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I've got 2 Ubuntu 10.04 Server virtual machines running on VirtualBox with host-only network static IP address configuration.

Machine A: ubuntu-a 192.168.56.101

Machine B: ubuntu-b 192.168.56.102

Machines can ping each other via either hostnames or IP address.

MySQL 5.1 installed on both systems. I want to achieve replication with ubuntu-a as the master and ubuntu-b as the slave.

I have a database name project1 on ubuntu-a that I want to replicate.

I've set up a user on the master with this command:

```
mysql> grant replication client, replication slave on *.* to repl@'%' identified by '!!abc123';
```

my.cnf on ubuntu-a (master):

```
server-id = 1
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = project1
```

my.cnf on ubuntu-b (slave):

```
server-id = 2
master-host = 192.168.56.101
master-user = repl
master-password = !!abc123
master-connect-retry = 60
replicate-do-db = project1
```

However, when I try to import the data to the slave I get this error:

```
mysql> load data from master;
ERROR 1158 (08S01): Got an error reading communication packets
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you login to the mysql master from the slave instance with the MySQL client (mysql -h192.168.56.101 -uyourusername -pyourpassword)@

Comment: Thanks!! I got error 111 when trying to do this and found the problem: By default, Ubuntu has a "bind-address = 127.0.0.1" line in my.cnf so it won't listen to remote hosts. I removed that and now I don't have this error.